# Meteor crash ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with Public folder

Tags: html, image, meteor

I have created a subfolder in meteor project folder called: public for image uploads in the html. this is what was suggested.
when I run it at localhost it gives me: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
on command prompt it exits the meteor.
when I remove the public folder and images, it works fine.
any ideas ???

Comment: Can you give an example of a file path and the URL that you tried for it?

Comment: I am using windows. my meteor files are in E drive and MyProj folder . so the public folder is : E:\MyProj\public\

Answer (score 0):

Your public folder probably has root permissions. There are two ways to fix this. You can put the public folder back and use `sudo meteor` to run the app or you can use `sudo chown -R yourusername public` in the root of the meteor project to change public folder permissions to your user. Then just use `meteor` to run the application as usual.

Comment: I am using windows 8.1 . These command are for linux aren't day?